# Cannot draw a BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I have a Player class

```
package game.player;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO; 
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import game.input.InputHandler;
import game.player.Missile;

public class Player{

private BufferedImage sprite;
public int x, y, width, height;
private final double speed = 5.0d;
private Missile missile;

public Player(int x, int y, int width, int height){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    try{
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("ship.png");
        sprite = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch(IOException e){}
}

public void keyPlayer(double delta, InputHandler i){
    if(i.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_D)){
        if(this.x>=1240) return;
        else this.x+=speed*delta;
    }

    if(i.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_A)){
        if(this.x<=0) return;
        else this.x-=speed*delta;
    }

    if(i.isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)){
        Missile missile = new Missile(this.x);
    }

}

public void update(InputHandler inputP){
    keyPlayer(2.0, inputP);
    if(missile != null) missile.update(0);
}

public void Draw(Graphics a){
    a.drawImage(sprite,x,y,width,height,null);
    if(missile!=null) a.drawImage(missile.spriteM,missile.x,missile.y,2,6,null);
}

public Rectangle getBounds(){
    return new Rectangle(x,y,width,height);
}
}
```

and a Missile class:

```
package game.player;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO; 
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Missile{

public BufferedImage spriteM;
public int x;
public int y=504;
private Timer timer2;

public Missile(int x){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=504;
    this.spriteM=spriteM;

    try{
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("missile.png");
        spriteM = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch(IOException e){}

    //Draw(game.ShooterGame.bbg);
    System.out.println("Missile launched!");
}

/*public void Draw(){
    g.drawImage(sprite,x,y,2,6,null);
}*/

public void update(int sec){
    System.out.println("Updating missile");
    timer2 = new Timer();
    timer2.schedule(new Move(), sec*1000);
}

class Move extends TimerTask{
    public void run(){
        if(2>1){
            y+=3;
        }
    }
}

}
```

The Player shoots a Missile, that goes flying on the screen, increasing its "y". My problem is: for some reason, the Missile does not appear on the screen(even though the "Missile launched!" appears), and I can´t figure out what is wrong.

I am using JFrame and drawImage to a backBuffer.getGraphics. My ideia is to draw the missile in the Player class, and not in the Missile class.

Thanks.

Comment: any `Exception`, or runtime error message?

Comment: If you want to move up on the panel, you have to decrement y.

Comment: If you're not sure why the image isn't shown, at least you shouldn't do things like `catch(IOException e){}` when loading... Also, you should edit the code to be a fully compilable and running example, without all the extra, unnecessary code. Posting everything is just laziness. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guesses are that either an `IOException` was thrown and the image was not loaded or that you should schedule a `repaint()` in the `JPanel` or wherever you are drawing your graphics.

Can you give us some more information?